# Spark Dataset: Table data not exactly same as of view from which it s created

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My code is exactly similar to this. Only changed variable and table names here. please ignore any syntax error during typing. Original code compiles successfully.

------CODE------

```
Dataset<Row> test = sqlContext.sql("select * from test_table");

test.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view_test");

sqlContext.sql("drop table if exist new_table");
sqlContext.sql("create table new_table as select * from temp_view_test");

//Code to print counts

//count if dataset
System.out.println("test count:"+test.count());

//count of temp view
Dataset<Row> tempViewTestData = sqlContext.sql("select * from temp_view_test");
System.out.println("temp view count: "+tempViewTestData.count());

//count of newly created table
Dataset<Row> newTableData = sqlContext.sql("select * from new_table");
System.out.println("New Table count: "+newTableData .count());
```

-----OUTPUT----

test count:9422720
temp view count: 9422720
New Table count: 9520364

-----QUESTION-----

My question is why count of new table differs from count of temp view. What should I do to make both counts same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution. It was because of Japanese characters present in dataset. One may consider this if similar issue arises.